# Data not bound for ListView on postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing some message panel as a user control. The code looks like this (shortened for clarity)

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindMessages(MessageType.Error, ErrListView);
}

 private void BindMessages(MessageType type, ListView target)
 {
    List<string> messages = Session.PopMessages(type);
    target.DataSource = messages;
    target.DataBind();
 }
```

ascx:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ErrListView">
    <ItemTemplate><li><%# Container.DataItem %></li></ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The code gets executed on each request (initial page load and postback) as it should, and the messages come out of the `SessionState` correctly. However, if the request is a postback, the messages are not actually updated (as if the `DataBind()` would not happen).

Anyone got a clue whats going on?

Comment: I wouldn't have the databind in the prerender - its too late in the page lifecycle for some things to work (you'll struggle with changes on postback maybe).

Comment: hm, then I need some other solution how to get my data to the client ... because obviously messages are generated by the events triggered so PreRender is the only place this can go.

Comment: @FrankyBoy, that should work nevertheless. Have you tried to debug to make sure `Session.PopMessages(type)` returns what you expect during the postback?

Comment: I would also debug and check if Session.PopMessage(type) returns the right value. you are overwriting the ViewState data when changing them on PreRender(), if you want to use some session or database to load the Messages, consider disabling ViewState. If you want to use ViewState you should recrerate your controls in the CreateChildControls() to ensure the contols have been created in time for the ViewState to populate the item.

Comment: Why don't you call the methods that do what they have to do from the events?

Comment: @Andrei: yeah, I checked that, getting the right stuff out. That's why its so weird.

Comment: @FrankyBoy, do you have ajax of any sort on the page? Update panels? If so, where does post back come from (inside or outside the UP) and where is the list view located?

Comment: @TimSchmelter because its a kind of message queue residing in the master view ... i.e. the idea is that views just push messages into it and on PreRender I would have rendered everything out.

Comment: @Andrei it works like (lol, wrong enter)
Master, has two elements, one is the pages, the other is the Message-Panel-UC. User clicks on stuff in SubPage which triggers the rest. UpdatePanel -> as I said, big noob in asp.net, so no clue what that is. Trying to sanitize some old app, this is my "current project" to unify the messaging.

Comment: EDIT: yep, reading up on UpdatePanel and using it fixed my "issue". Thx to @Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I failed here was that my content did not contain an UpdatePanel. Changing my ascx file to include said control resolved my issues.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="StatusUpdatePanel">
<ContentTemplate>

    <ul Class="Errors">
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ErrListView">
        <ItemTemplate><li><%# Container.DataItem %></li></ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
    </ul>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```